# Why won't Character.toString((char)i) work in a certain place

Tags: java

I have an Issue with converting ints to chars to print out. I have a program going just for the hell of it that is for Graph theory(a class i'm in at the moment). Everything works fine except for one thing.

I have classes to create different types of graphs. There is a Node class to make Nodes for the graphs. they hold values and names, the names are letters based on the character value of the int. when a Graph is created each nodes is is created like this

```
Node(String name, int value).
```

Here is an Example of a Node being created.

```
int a = 97;
int alpha = a+i-1;
int alphaCnt = 0;
if(alpha < 123 && alphaCnt == 0){
    String nodeName = Character.toString((char)alpha);
    Node node = new Node(nodeName, i);
    this.addnode(node);
}
```

This works perfectly fine. The name becomes "a" if i=1 "b" if i=2 and so on.
The problem I have is when I print the code in the toString for the Graph.

At first I had it printing just the array of numbers, but when it printed the nodes no one would know what number goes with what nodes. So I decided to add the character after the number like this. [2(b), 1(a)...5(e)].

But using the exact same conversions wont work.
My toString method.(Part of it). pCode is the int array of the code. Each number in the code I had put into an array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < pCode.length; i++){
    String x = Character.toString((char)(i+1));
    if(i != pCode.length){
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(pCode[i]) + "(" + x + ")");
        System.out.println(x.toString());
        System.out.println(Character.toString((char)(i+1)));
        System.out.println(Character.toString((char)pCode[i]));
    }
}
```

There's probly something right under my nose but no matter what i do I cannot get the character to print with the number I cant even get it to print by itself.

Why does Character.toString((char)intVal)) work when I create a node but not when i just want to print the character value of the int.

Comment: What's the type of `pCode`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When these two lines are run:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pCode.length; i++){
    String x = Character.toString((char)(i+1));
    ...
```

`x` will be set first to a string containing the SOH character, then next to the STX character, and so on---all ASCII control characters.  Those won't work very well when you include them in a larger string and try to print it out.  Maybe you meant `(char)(i+97)`?  I'm not sure.

Comment: P.S. Character literals like `'a'` are treated as integers when used in computation.  I'd recommend using those instead of "magic numbers" like 97, because they make the code easier to understand; similarly instead of `123` use `'z'-1`.

Comment: wow I totally didn't see it. I was doing 1 instead of 97. Thank you very much

Comment: It was giving me weird funky characters instead of a-z because i set it to 1 instead of starting at 97. I'll try doing the character computation too.

Answer (score 0):

Try `String.valueOf((char) i);` instead.

Comment: `Character.toString(char)` uses `String.valueOf(char)` internally.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse characters to int directly:

```
int x = (int)'a';
```